# Replace/update data in Switch case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The action data contains an array, I want, according to the id, to replace a specific array with new data. But it turns out that instead of updating one array, I get 3 array elements that contain other arrays.

Other records that do not match by id should remain the same

```js
 case UpdateOneBank:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.map((p) => p._id === action.data._id?action.data:state.data),}
```

data state
[image: old data state]

New data
[image: New data]
Update only one array, not to add 3 in to 2 remain arrays
[image]

Comment: You are returning `state.data` in else condition.
make it `p`.

Everytime you are entering in `else` condition, you are pushing your own `state.data` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case UpdateOneBank:
  return {
    ...state,
    data: state.data.map((p) => p._id === action.data._id?action.data:p),}
```

Try this

You were returning the entire data in else condition, not an item of map.

Answer (score 1):

---

### Solution

```
   case UpdateOneBank:
        return {
           ...state,
           data: state.data.map((originalValue) => originalValue._id === action.data._id?  action.data:  originalValue),}
```

---

### Error

Instead of doing this:

```
case UpdateOneBank:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.map((originalValue) => originalValue._id === action.data._id?  action.data:  state.data),}
```

---

### Reason

`Note:  Everytime you are entering in else condition, you are pushing/returning your own` **state.data** `array`